# Issues connecting ASP.NET Core Application to MariaDb Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, mariadb

I'm running Web API Core application locally. Now, I'm trying to run it in container on a server and getting error *Table 'databasename.Table' doesn't exist.* The connection with database is established, but it cannot access tables' content for some reason. I have tried different connection string options:

> "DefaultConnection":"server=localhost;port=3306;database=databaseName;uid=myUsername;password=Test1234;AllowZeroDateTime=True;"

> "DefaultConnection":"server=172.17.0.2;port=3306;database=databaseName;...

> "DefaultConnection":"server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=databaseName;...

The docker run commands I tried:

> sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000 -e DB_HOST=localhost -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_USER=test -e DB_PASSWORD=Test1234 -e DB_NAME=databaseName --name containerName

> sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000 -e DB_HOST=localhost -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_USER=test -e DB_PASSWORD=Test1234 -e DB_NAME=databaseName --network="host" --name containerName

> ... DB_HOST=172.17.0.2

> ... DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

I granted privileges to all the users, and I can access the database and its tables:

```html
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| csvi               |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| databasename       |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

I'm a bit lost now, not sure where the problem lies, could it be the connection string? Is my docker run command correct?

Answer (score 0):

"The problem lies in naming the table. The table in the database is called databasename.record. In the DbContext, I set it up like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Record> Record { get; set; }
}
```

Although the name of the table is "record", I could still retrieve data even though the public property is "Record". The capital 'R' is not causing any problems when running it locally, but when running it in a container on Linux, it resulted in the error "table doesn't exist". After changing it to "record", everything worked fine:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Record> record { get; set; }
}
```

The root cause of the problem was the [database collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-ver16).